# Ssh to remote server through windows batch

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

Can anyone suggest me how I can use Windows Batch Program to `ssh` to remote server and then execute `shell scripts` over there?

Any simple sample example will be good for me to start on this.

Server Name:- `ares-ingest.vip.host.com`

Username:-   `uname`

Password:-   `password`

Any suggestions will be appreciated as I am new to Windows Batch Program

**Update:-**

I tried using `plink` to execute the shell script that I have on my local machine and I always get the error like below, Is there anything wrong I am doing?

```
C:\PLINK>plink uname@cli.host.com -m email.sh
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Your Kerberos password will expire in 73 days.

sh: HIVE_OPTS= -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology: is not an identifier
```

Below is the content in my shell script-

```
#!/bin/bash
export HIVE_OPTS="$HIVE_OPTS -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology"
hive -S -e 'SELECT count(*) from testingtable2' > attachment.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [plink](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) to send your commands over.

```
Usage: plink [options] [user@]host [command]
```

Comment: I will check that link out, but if you can provide me one example fulfilling my requirements, that will be great for me to understand.

Comment: I have updated my question as after using plink by executing shell script on the remote server, I am getting errors and I have no idea why is it coming. Can you help me out here?